# Unicode and incorrect number of arguments errors with Python 3 and MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, prepared-statement

I'm trying to execute a simple SELECT query on a MySQL(MariaDB) database in Python 3.

I'm getting very weird errors

```py
        query = (
            'SELECT user_id, user_password_hash, user_password_salt '
            'FROM users '
            'WHERE user_username = "%s"'
        )

        print(f'Trying login, username {username}, password {password}')

        try:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor(prepared=True)
            cursor.execute(query, (username,))

            results = cursor.fetchone()

            print(results)
            ...

        except Error as e:
            print('Error in login query: ' + str(e))
            raise e
```

Running this code gives me the following error:
`Error in login query: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement`

I don't understand - it requires one argument, and I've given it one argument. 
Removing the comma in the tuple in `execute()` doesn't fix this problem.

Now, if I remove the quotes from the query, I get an entirely different error:

```py
        query = (
            'SELECT user_id, user_password_hash, user_password_salt '
            'FROM users '
            'WHERE user_username = %s'
        )
```

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 0: invalid start byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'> returned a result with an error set
```

The table is using utf8mb4, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Also, running `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username="jeff"` in the MySQL console works fine.

This should be a really trivial query, but I've got absolutely no idea what's going on - any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: When experimenting in an isolated Python process, I reproduced the problem by running this:

```py
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                               database="lucidlab",
                               user="lucidlab",
                               password="lucidlab")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='jeff'")

results = cur.fetchall() # ERROR
print(results)
```

This makes me think that perhaps it's a database encoding problem?

EDIT: I've solved the problem. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you specify `charset='utf8'` in the call to `connect`?

Comment: The only difference is that now I get `Invalid continuation byte` instead of `Invalid start byte`.

Comment: It seems like an encoding problem, but without the schema and data that reproduce the problem, or complete tracebacks, it's difficult to know exactly what the problem might be.  I'd be inclined to suggest trying different encodings in the connection (which you are probably trying anyway)

Comment: It was an encoding problem, but it was an encoding going the opposite direction. Binary data was being stored in the database, which python was automatically converting to a UTF-8 string internally - and failing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. Fixing it required looking at the schema, which I unfortunately didn't post - lesson learned.

My schema contained the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
...
  user_password_hash BINARY(20) NOT NULL,
  user_password_salt BINARY(20) NOT NULL,
...
);
```

Running a `SELECT * FROM users...` query of *any kind* retrieves this binary data, which Python helpfully(!) immediately converts to a UTF-8 string... which fails, as the salt is bytes produced from `os.urandom()`.

I fixed this by instead using `sha256_crypt` from the `passlib` library, and storing my encoded hash+salt combination as a `CHAR(77)`.

Thanks to those who helped - unfortunately, I was thinking about the problem too narrowly, and had therefore phrased my question as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotation marks:

```
    query = ("SELECT user_id, user_password_hash, user_password_salt "
        "FROM users "
        "WHERE user_username = %s"
    )
```

or tripple quotations:

```
    query = ("""SELECT user_id, user_password_hash, user_password_salt 
        FROM users 
        WHERE user_username = %s"""
    )
```

---

Comment: ```query = (
            "SELECT user_id, user_password_hash, user_password_salt "
            "FROM users "
            "WHERE user_username = %s"
        )
```
gives me the unicode error I described above - i.e. `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: Edit: triple quotes do the same thing. Thanks for replying so quickly, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

`query = """SELECT user_id, user_password_hash, user_password_salt
            FROM users
            WHERE user_username = %s"""`

use this it will work..

Comment: This doesn't work - it gives me the unicode decode error I mentioned in the question 

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 0: invalid start byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'> returned a result with an error set`